# Bad performance applying blur with StackBlur for animation with fade

Tags: javascript, performance, canvas, transition, blur

I have a canvas that does a transition with many images applying a alpha for the fade. The problem is that for each frame apply the blur and that do very slow the animation.

If before apply the transition, do a copy of canva and apply the blur, and after use this canvas for draw in the other canvas, the animation fade no work.

The code is the next:

```
        function animateFade()
            if (fadePct > 100) {
                return;
            }
            requestAnimationFrame(animateFade);

            draw(imgs[fadeInIndex], fadePct / 100);

            draw(imgs[fadeOutIndex], (1 - fadePct / 100));

            fadePct++;
        }
        function draw(image, opacity) {
            ctx.save();
            ctx.globalAlpha = opacity;

            ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
             StackBlur.canvasRGB(canvas, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height, 50);
            ctx.restore();
        }

         imageURLs = []; // put the paths to your images here
        imagesOK = 0;
        imgs = [];
        var items = $('.carrousel .post');
        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            image = items.eq(i).find("img").attr('src');
            imageURLs.push(image);
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < imageURLs.length; i++) {
            img = new Image();
            imgs.push(img);
            img.onload = function () {
                imagesOK++;
                if (imagesOK >= imageURLs.length) {

                    ctx.drawImage(imgs[0], 0, 0);

                    var ratio = 1;
                    ratio =  $('#best_game').width() / img.width;

                    canvas.width = img.width * ratio;
                    canvas.height = img.height * ratio;
                    ctx.drawImage(imgs[0], 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

                    StackBlur.canvasRGB(canvas, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height, 50);

                }
            };
            img.onerror = function () {
                alert("image load failed");
            }
            img.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
            img.src = imageURLs[i];
        }


        canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
        ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
         });
```

Comment: The slow performance when doing many blurs is to be expected. Blurring requires comparing all pixels against their neighbors and is therefore computationally expensive. Stackoverflow member K3N has written a nice [blur script](https://github.com/epistemex/realtime-blur-js) that works a bit faster than stackblur. You might give it a try.

Comment: Thanks markE. The problem is that you lose a lot of quality to gain speed.

Comment: Yes, as it often is, you must trade between quality and speed. As the designer, you get to choose the trade-off.

Comment: Yeah, but is nothing wrong in my code that cause the very slowly in the transition fade?, not exist a better way?...if not i will have to use the blur in css3.

Comment: Yes, what's "wrong" is that you are using StackBlur that itself intensively manipulates pixels to achieve its effect. That's the nature of blurring -- it's not StackBlur's fault. There is no significantly better way in 2D canvas. You can use WebGL to get much better performance.

Comment: Yes, in first plan I`m went for WebGL but not liked the blur effect, is less natural that canvas, for that use after canvas but i not have other option that come back to WebGL.
Thanks markE for the fast reply.